# JTable TableCellRenderer getTableCellRendererComponent() never called

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I am trying to implement a `JTable` which will format cells in columns in ways depending on their type. I am implementing TableCellRenderer's `getTableCellRendererComponent()' method to achieve this.

The problem is that my `getTableCellRendererComponent()` method never seems to be called, as the test output in the code never appears in the console.

Here is the code for the renderer:

```
public class MenuSheetTableCellRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                        JTable table, Object value,
                        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                        int row, int column){

JLabel label = new JLabel();

System.out.println("test");
if( value instanceof GregorianCalendar ){
    System.out.println("test2");
    GregorianCalendar timeGregorianCalendar = (GregorianCalendar) value;
    Date time = timeGregorianCalendar.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    String mealTime = timeFormat.format(time);

    label.setText(mealTime);
}

else if( value instanceof MealChoice){
    label.setText(value.toString());
}   
else if( value instanceof Recipe){
    label.setText("     " + value.toString());
}
if (value instanceof String || value instanceof MealChoice){
    label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
}

return label;
}
```

}

Here is the code (edited for relevant code) which generates the table. Note that getRows() is my custom method that returns the data to be rendered and also that I am using netbeans (hence the abridged initComponents() method). Should be irrelevant.

```
private void initComponents() {
menuSheetTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
menuSheetTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {

        }
    ));
    menuSheetTable.setEnabled(false);
    menuSheetTable.setFocusable(false);
    menuSheetTable.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
    menuSheetTable.setShowVerticalLines(false);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(menuSheetTable);
}

public void renderTable(){

String[] columns = { "Sunday", "Monday","Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday" }; 
Object[][] rows = getRows();

DefaultTableModel menuSheetModel = new DefaultTableModel( rows, columns );
menuSheetTable.setModel( menuSheetModel );

MenuSheetTableCellRenderer renderer = new MenuSheetTableCellRenderer();
try{
   menuSheetTable.setDefaultRenderer(Class.forName("java.lang.String"), renderer);
   menuSheetTable.setDefaultRenderer(Class.forName("java.util.GregorianCalendar"), renderer); 
   menuSheetTable.setDefaultRenderer(Class.forName("MenuSystemManager.MealChoice"), renderer);
   menuSheetTable.setDefaultRenderer(Class.forName("MenuSystemManager.Recipe"), renderer);
}
catch( ClassNotFoundException e){
    System.exit(1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code which set the default renderers doesn't have the `Object` object registered. Because the `rows[][]` was declared to hold type "Object," the renderer was never called because it was passed `Object` objects, not `GregorianCalendar`s, `String`s, or `Recipe`s.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Well, you have already found the reason why it behaves like this. So, here is the solution.

`JTable` works with `TableModel` interface that supplies table with all information about the data it holds. This information also contains the class associated with a column. So basically, what you need to do is to derive `TableModel` or `AbstractTableModel` with your class which will hold the data for the table and override the method `public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex)`.
After that enhancement you can use your custom `TableCellRenderer`.
In your code you supplied `JTable` with a `DefaultTableModel` which returns `Object` for any column and that's why it did not work out.